# Как добиться 100% покрытия тестами кода в блоке try-catch?

Tags: java, исключения, junit, code-coverage

У меня есть метод который по показаниям jacoco протестирован на 74%:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне кажется что я протестировал все что можно. Скажите как мне закрыть эту строку? И почему при отлове исключения в тесте она считается не покрытой?
Тесты которые покрывают класс:

```
@Test
public void whenAddressAddSuccessThenReturnID() throws SQLException {

    final PropertiesLoader properties = mock(PropertiesLoader.class);
    when(properties.get("add_address")).thenReturn("mock_script");

    final ResultSet set = mock(ResultSet.class);
    when(set.getInt(1)).thenReturn(1);
    when(set.next()).thenReturn(true);

    final PreparedStatement statement = mock(PreparedStatement.class);
    when(statement.executeQuery()).thenReturn(set);

    final Connection connection = mock(Connection.class);
    when(connection.prepareStatement("mock_script")).thenReturn(statement);

    final AddressAdder adder =
            new AddressAdder(connection, properties);

    final Address address = new Address("test", "test");
    final int result = adder.addAddress(address);

    Assert.assertThat(result, is(1));

    verify(properties).get("add_address");
    verify(connection).prepareStatement("mock_script");
    verify(statement).setString(1, "test");
    verify(statement).setString(2, "test");
    verify(statement).executeQuery();
    verify(set).next();
    verify(set).getInt(1);
}

@Test
public void whenPrepareStatementTrowSQLException() throws SQLException {

    final PropertiesLoader properties = mock(PropertiesLoader.class);
    when(properties.get("add_address")).thenReturn("mock_script");

    final Connection connection = mock(Connection.class);
    when(connection.prepareStatement("mock_script"))
            .thenThrow(mock(SQLException.class));


    final AddressAdder adder =
            new AddressAdder(connection, properties);

    final Address address = new Address("test", "test");
    final int result = adder.addAddress(address);

    Assert.assertThat(result, is(-1));

    verify(properties).get("add_address");

    verify(connection).prepareStatement("mock_script");
}

@Test
public void whenGetIntTrowSQLException() throws SQLException {

    final PropertiesLoader properties = mock(PropertiesLoader.class);
    when(properties.get("add_address")).thenReturn("mock_script");

    final ResultSet set = mock(ResultSet.class);
    when(set.getInt(1)).thenThrow(mock(SQLException.class));
    when(set.next()).thenReturn(true);

    final PreparedStatement statement = mock(PreparedStatement.class);
    when(statement.executeQuery()).thenReturn(set);

    final Connection connection = mock(Connection.class);
    when(connection.prepareStatement("mock_script")).thenReturn(statement);

    final AddressAdder adder =
            new AddressAdder(connection, properties);

    final Address address = new Address("test", "test");
    final int result = adder.addAddress(address);

    Assert.assertThat(result, is(-1));

    verify(properties).get("add_address");
    verify(connection).prepareStatement("mock_script");
    verify(statement).setString(1, "test");
    verify(statement).setString(2, "test");
    verify(statement).executeQuery();
    verify(set).next();
    verify(set).getInt(1);
}

@Test
public void whenNextReturnFalseThenReturnFailFlag() throws SQLException {

    final PropertiesLoader properties = mock(PropertiesLoader.class);
    when(properties.get("add_address")).thenReturn("mock_script");

    final ResultSet set = mock(ResultSet.class);
    when(set.next()).thenReturn(false);

    final PreparedStatement statement = mock(PreparedStatement.class);
    when(statement.executeQuery()).thenReturn(set);

    final Connection connection = mock(Connection.class);
    when(connection.prepareStatement("mock_script")).thenReturn(statement);

    final AddressAdder adder =
            new AddressAdder(connection, properties);

    final Address address = new Address("test", "test");
    final int result = adder.addAddress(address);

    Assert.assertThat(result, is(-1));

    verify(properties).get("add_address");
    verify(connection).prepareStatement("mock_script");
    verify(statement).setString(1, "test");
    verify(statement).setString(2, "test");
    verify(statement).executeQuery();
    verify(set).next();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> И почему при отлове исключения в тесте она считается не покрытой?

Потому что тут:

```
 when(connection.prepareStatement("mock_script"))
            .thenThrow(mock(SQLException.class));
```

Вы просто глушили `SQLException`. Исключения в `JUnit` тестируются немножко иначе:

```
@Test(expected = SQLException.class)
public void whenPrepareStatementTrowSQLException() throws SQLException {

    final PropertiesLoader properties = mock(PropertiesLoader.class);
    when(properties.get("add_address")).thenReturn("mock_script");

    final Connection connection = mock(Connection.class);


    final AddressAdder adder =
            new AddressAdder(connection, properties);

    final Address address = new Address("test", "test");
    final int result = adder.addAddress(address);

    Assert.assertThat(result, is(-1));

    verify(properties).get("add_address");

    verify(connection).prepareStatement("mock_script");
}
```

[code-coverage](/questions/tagged/code-coverage)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Скажите, а разве анатация `(expected = SQLException.class)` будет работать если исключение поймано в `catch`?

Comment: Да, именно в этом и заключается логика. Этой аннотацией вы предупреждаете что будет сброшено исключение и тест будет пройден только в том случае если оно действительно будет сброшено.